# Little confused with C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following:

```
        extern Keyboard keyboard;

        enum DEVICETYPE
        {
            KEYBOARD,
            MOUSE,
            CONTROLLER,
            TOUCH
        };

        template <typename T>
        class PlayerInputDevice
        {
        public:
            void SetDevice( DEVICETYPE deviceType )
            {
                switch( deviceType )
                {
                case KEYBOARD:
                    Device = &keyboard;
                    break;
                }
            }

            T Device;
        };
```

I'm getting compile errors:

```
Error   1   error C2955: 'Game::Model::Input::PlayerInputDevice' : use of class template requires template argument list (Concrete\Player.cpp)  c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\games\jimmy\model\concrete\player.h    29  1   Model
Error   2   error C2512: 'Game::Model::Input::PlayerInputDevice' : no appropriate default constructor available c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\games\jimmy\model\concrete\player.cpp  8   1   Model
Error   6   error C2955: 'Game::Model::Input::PlayerInputDevice' : use of class template requires template argument list    c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\games\jimmy\model\concrete\player.h    29  1   Game
        7   IntelliSense: argument list for class template "Game::Model::Input::PlayerInputDevice" is missing   c:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Games\Jimmy\Model\Concrete\Player.h    29  5   Model
```

Not sure I'm understanding this correctly?

I would like to be able to say something like this:

```
class Player
{
public:    
    PlayerInputDevice PlayerInputDevice;
}

...

player.PlayerInputDevice.SetDevice( KEYBOARD );
player.PlayerInputDevice.IsUpPressed();
```

Comment: Data members can't have their own template (although I'd be interested in seeing if it works with variable templates). It must be applied to the class.

Comment: you mean template<typename T> above the class or make it a template class?

Comment: Those should be about the same thing.

Comment: Oh I thought classes were: template <class T>

Comment: `typename` and `class` are interchangeable there.

Comment: In general, I don't really see what the point of the template parameter is here. You use it to make the type of `Device` variadic, but then you don't carry the type requirement to the setter for it. It seems you could just make `Device` of type `DEVICETYPE `

Comment: For anyone interested, I did actually try this with variable template. No luck.

Comment: The idea is (and i'm probably completely mad) that it would be cool to call a function to set the device to one property variable... thereby any future calls are not tightly coupled to type... as long as my pure virtuals are implemented, there would be no issue across device types (IsUpPressed is a pure virtual if you were wondering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PlayerInputDevice` is a template class so to use it, you need a template argument, as the compiler says. E.g.

```
class Player
{
public:    
    PlayerInputDevice<Device> playerInputDevice;
};
```

where `Device` is some type appropriate for your application.

Note I've changed the name of the data member to `playerInputDevice`; it cannot be the same with the name of the class.

Comment: Oh really? so the compiler does not know I mean it to be the variable name? daymm, and there I was coming up with a nice new naming convention for Domain Models

Comment: Being a compiler is a tough job :-)

Comment: lol, #virtualbeers for all the compilers. :) Thanks, learnt lots on this one.

Comment: It does know the difference by the way. managed to get this to work and it knows that one is the type and the other is the var name.

Comment: Wow, I was so sure I have never tried :-) Clang accepts it, however GCC declines it (says the declaration of the variable changes the meaning of the type). I would still have my reservations whether it is valid.